# How to setup Azure Classic service endpoint using Management Certificate in Visual Studio online

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cloud-services, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup Continuous Deployment from Visual studio online to Azure for my cloud service project (ccproj)

Inside VSO, I created an '*Azure classic service endpoint*', that uses Certificate based connection. (By restriction I can not use the 'credentials'.)

When verifying the connection, I get a exception message saying:

> Invalid Azure Management certificate. Exception Message: Cannot find the requested object.**

Question is: 
**What type of information do I need to fill in inside the Managment Certificate textbox field?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to these steps to get certificate:

1. Click [publish settings file](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=312990) hyperlink (It will redirect to [certificate download page](https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index?client=vsserverexplorer&schemaversion=2.0))
2. Open downloaded file (XXX.publishsettings) via **notepad**
3. The value of **Id** is the **Subscription Id**
4. The value of **name** is **Subscription Name**
5. The value of **ManagementCertificate** is **Management Certificate**.

The publishsettings file content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishData>
  <PublishProfile
    SchemaVersion="2.0"
    PublishMethod="AzureServiceManagementAPI">
    <Subscription
      ServiceManagementUrl="https://management.core.windows.net"
      Id="[Subscription Id]"
      Name="[Subscription Name]"
      ManagementCertificate="[Management Certificate]" />
  </PublishProfile>
</PublishData>
```